# Drag files out of a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, copy

Hello I would like to be able to drag a row out of a datagridview to copy a file to the location I drop it.

Rows are single select and I have a file path column that has the full source path for the row's file.

Is there something I can do with DragLeave to hold on to that file path and when I release the mouse perform the copy?

Ended up using a modifier key, but it works. Only for one file at a time because of how I programmed my context menu.

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
{
      //Drag out
      string[] selectedFiles = new String[1];
      selectedFile[0] = filesGrid[pathColumn.Index,filesGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index].Value.ToString();
      DataObject dragData = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, selectedFiles);
      dragData.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, selectedFiles[0]);
      DoDragDrop(dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12539/How-to-drag-information-from-a-DataGridView-contro) might be just what you are looking for. Please let me know if it helped:)

As for the Drag on Desktop or Explorer I found this article [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/60f3ef88-ff7d-4846-b28f-3c97dcef7583/).

Comment: looks like it does a great job of outlining out to move data from one control to another, the datagridview to a list box, however I'm unsure of what to do after the start of the drag. If I were to do like a Ctrl+Left Click as that author suggested, there is no DragEnter or DragDrop properties for the Desktop that I'm aware of.

Comment: I woudn't be so sure ;)   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/60f3ef88-ff7d-4846-b28f-3c97dcef7583/

Comment: i'll mark as the answer, question edited to show code. I can only drop one file at a time because I have to have multiselect off (context menu limitations), but it's better than nothing in my case. thanks.